# Python: Counting values in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
    attendance = {5: ['Irving', 'Sarah'],
                  1: ['Bill'],
                  2: ['Sarah', 'Fred'],
                  7: ['Paul', 'Alice', 'Irving'],
                  8: ['Bill', 'Fred', 'Sarah'],
                  3: ['Alice', 'Bob'],
                  4: ['David', 'Paul', 'Tom']}

    for keys, values in attendance.items():
        for x in values:
            print(keys, " : ", len(x))
```

I am trying to count the number of values in dictionary using `len()`, but the values I get are wrong.
I am new to Python so can you kindly explain in simple terms? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iteration over `dict.items()` yields tuple of a **single** key and it's value. It seems like you are printing the `len` of every single string, instead of the list. You should be doing something like this:

```
In [2]:     attendance = {5: ['Irving', 'Sarah'],
   ...:                   1: ['Bill'],
   ...:                   2: ['Sarah', 'Fred'],
   ...:                   7: ['Paul', 'Alice', 'Irving'],
   ...:                   8: ['Bill', 'Fred', 'Sarah'],
   ...:                   3: ['Alice', 'Bob'],
   ...:                   4: ['David', 'Paul', 'Tom']}
   ...: 
   ...:     for key, value in attendance.items():
   ...:         print(key, " : ", len(value))
1  :  1
2  :  2
3  :  2
4  :  3
5  :  2
7  :  3
8  :  3
```